# What is Microsoft Visual Studio Shell Isolated and Integrated? Is it good idea to remove them?

Tags: uninstall, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

I have Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 installed on my computer. Before this, I had Visual Studio 2015 and 2012. Their installers installed another Visual Studio versions and they are taking a lot of space on my PC.

[image: Visual Studio Shell]

I am planning on removing them. Is it a good idea? What are these by the way? And does removing them will affect my VS2017 installation?

Comment: you have, or had a piece of software that used VS shell as a "house" for their components to run within. your question depends entirely on whether you still have whatever piece of software. I recall certian versions of SQLServer tools like the BI toolkit or older versions of the DataTools packages ran in isolated shell.

Comment: Only you can determine if you need them installed.  Windows will function without them.

Comment: "What are these by the way? "   "You can create your own Visual Studio-based application in either integrated or isolated mode. In integrated mode, many Visual Studio features are available in addition to your application. In the isolated mode, you choose a subset of Visual Studio features that you wish to distribute along with your own extension"...https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bb685612(v=vs.60)